# django Signals not working as expected

Tags: django, django-signals

I am trying to create a project for creating feeds/activity feeds of a user with the help of a [blog](http://ryanberg.net/blog/2008/jun/24/basics-creating-tumblelog-django/).

These are the models -

```
class StreamItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    @property 
    def content_class(self):
        return self.content_type.model


class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

And this is the signals.py:

```
__init__.py
from django.db.models import signals
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.dispatch import dispatcher
from blogs.models import Blog
from picture.models import Photo
from models import StreamItem

def create_stream_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):

    # Check to see if the object was just created for the first time

    if 'created' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['created']:
            create = True

            # Get the instance's content type

            ctype = ContentType.object.get_for_model(instance)

            if create:
                si = StreamItem.objects.get_or_create(user=instance.user, content_type=ctype, object_id=instance.id, pub_date = instance.pub_date)

 # Send a signal on post_save for each of these models

for modelname in [Blog, Photo]:
    dispatcher.connect(create_stream_item, signal=signals.post_save, sender=modelname)
```

When I create a blog or upload a photo, the `signal` does not work. And I am not getting any error too. But I can manually add items to the `StreamItem` app using the admin, and the StreamItem does work as I want it to be. I think there's problem with the signals.py. Please help me out. Would be much appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make sure that the signals are loaded soon after django is started.
The one possible way to ensure it is to import the module into `__init__.py`

```
# __init__.py
# add the below line and run the project again
import signals
```

Comment: Hello. I have added `__init__.py` in the signals.py. But even now it doesnt work. Is there anyway to check the errors?

Comment: By the way, do I have to place `import signals` to `__init__.py` file. Or place the `__init__.py` in the `signals.py` file?

Comment: @Aamu In the app modules you will have `__init__.py` which are definitely loaded when django is loaded. so, drop `import signals` line in that

Comment: Ok, now I think that works... But I am getting another error:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'`

Comment: Ok, I had to change some of the code, and it worked. But `import signals` in init.py file did solved the firing up of the signals. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure the code is actually loaded before it will do anything. I usually define any signal handlers I want in the same file as the necessary model definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've omitted code, the new `si` item your signal handler creates is missing the required field `user`. You probably need to add that to your `get_or_create` call.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. And yes, I didn't added the user. But now, even after I have added, it does not create a new stream item.